# pysharkを使ってpcapファイルを解析する際のRuntimeError

Tags: python, wireshark

```
cap = pyshark.FileCapture(pcapfile)
print(cap[0])
```

このようなコードを動かしたいだけなのですが、以下のようなエラーコードが出てしまいます。

> RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running

色々調べてnest_asyncio.apply()など試しましたが解決方法がわかりません。
どなたかわかる方いましたらよろしくお願いします。

Comment: こんな記事がありますが、jupyter-notobook/lab等で実行していますか？ [Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running #360](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark/issues/360), [Pyshark cannot run event loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67434088/9014308) 例えばjupyter関連ならば、そうではないpython単体の環境で実行してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 確かにVSコード入れてできました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントで解決したようなので、それを情報として回答にしておきます。

こちらのpysharkのIsuueやStackOverflow英語版の記事によると、Jupyter-Notebook/LabあるいはGoogleColab関連の環境で実行していると発生する問題のようです。
[Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running #360](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark/issues/360)
[Pyshark cannot run event loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67434088/9014308)

Issueには質問にもあった`nest_asyncio.apply()`や他に`tornade`を使う案(版数が上がると出来なくなる？)も出ていましたが、`IDLE`で動作したという報告があるように結局はPython単独の環境で実行することで正常に動作するようです。

質問者さんはVSCodeから実行することで動作したようです。